# OpenLayers request tiles out of range

Tags: maps, openlayers, tile

OpenLayers map is requesting tiles out of range and all the map is pink.
If I inspect single tile, the address is next:

> /Tiles/15/**16384**/16384.png

But the folder with generated tiles does not contain such values:
The range is only: /Tiles/15/**16099** - /Tiles/15/**16119**

The tiles are generated by Maperitive.

Is it a Maperitive problem or I should set additional options to OpenLayers.Map?

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("demoMap");
var cLayer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("New Layer", 
"http://localhost:15157/Map/Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", { numZoomLevels: 19 });
map.addLayer(cLayer2);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

Comment: problem was resolved: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41190/openlayers-request-tiles-out-of-range/41280#41280